# How to display specific data fetched from database using json with PHP

Tags: php, json

My code is

```
<?php /*My PHP/JSON 
              Code */
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");/*establish connection*/
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

mysql_select_db("TEACHER", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from TEACHER") or die('Could not query');
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $test_data[]=$row;
    }
    $json['employees']=$test_data;
}
$encoded = json_encode($json);
echo $encoded;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo var_dump(json_decode($encoded));
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
$tmp_array = json_decode($encoded);

echo "List of Teachers";
echo "<br />";
echo "---------------------------------";
echo "<br />";
foreach($tmp_array->employees as $item)
{
    echo $item[0] . " " . $item[1];
    echo "<br />";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

the output of my code is

```
{"employees":[["Glenn","Quagmire","33"],["Rakesh","Mittal","25"],["Nagraj","Kondikoppa","23"],["Kishore","K","28"],["Raghu","Dixit","35"],["Rajesh","Kulkarni","36"],["Aakash","Gupta","45"],["Sangmesh","Itgampalli","29"],["Siddu","C","48"],["Raju","Chidri","29"],["Ram","Kumar","58"],["Roopa","Patil","23"],["Jagdeesh","manthale","26"],["Satish","kharge","29"],["Shiv","Gada","26"],["Sheela","Kukotte","26"],["Ajay","K","23"],["Prakash","Nandi","23"],["Prasanna","Mumbai","28"],["Vishwa","Saineer","23"],["Arjun","sarja","55"]]}
```

object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["employees"]=> array(21) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Glenn" [1]=> string(8) "Quagmire" [2]=> string(2) "33" } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Rakesh" [1]=> string(6) "Mittal" [2]=> string(2) "25" } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Nagraj" [1]=> string(10) "Kondikoppa" [2]=> string(2) "23" } [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "Kishore" [1]=> string(1) "K" [2]=> string(2) "28" } [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Raghu" [1]=> string(5) "Dixit" [2]=> string(2) "35" } [5]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Rajesh" [1]=> string(8) "Kulkarni" [2]=> string(2) "36" } [6]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Aakash" [1]=> string(5) "Gupta" [2]=> string(2) "45" } [7]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Sangmesh" [1]=> string(10) "Itgampalli" [2]=> string(2) "29" } [8]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Siddu" [1]=> string(1) "C" [2]=> string(2) "48" } [9]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Raju" [1]=> string(6) "Chidri" [2]=> string(2) "29" } [10]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "Ram" [1]=> string(5) "Kumar" [2]=> string(2) "58" } [11]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Roopa" [1]=> string(5) "Patil" [2]=> string(2) "23" } [12]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Jagdeesh" [1]=> string(8) "manthale" [2]=> string(2) "26" } [13]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Satish" [1]=> string(6) "kharge" [2]=> string(2) "29" } [14]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Shiv" [1]=> string(4) "Gada" [2]=> string(2) "26" } [15]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Sheela" [1]=> string(7) "Kukotte" [2]=> string(2) "26" } [16]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Ajay" [1]=> string(1) "K" [2]=> string(2) "23" } [17]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "Prakash" [1]=> string(5) "Nandi" [2]=> string(2) "23" } [18]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Prasanna" [1]=> string(6) "Mumbai" [2]=> string(2) "28" } [19]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "Vishwa" [1]=> string(7) "Saineer" [2]=> string(2) "23" } [20]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Arjun" [1]=> string(5) "sarja" [2]=> string(2) "55" } } }

### List of Teachers

Glenn Quagmire
Rakesh Mittal
Nagraj Kondikoppa
Kishore K
Raghu Dixit
Rajesh Kulkarni
Aakash Gupta
Sangmesh Itgampalli
Siddu C
Raju Chidri
Ram Kumar
Roopa Patil
Jagdeesh manthale
Satish kharge
Shiv Gada
Sheela Kukotte
Ajay K
Prakash Nandi
Prasanna Mumbai
Vishwa Saineer
Arjun sarja

Comment: Edit has removed what the poster wanted the data to be like.

Answer (score 0):

1- decode first, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
    $tmp_array = json_decode($data);
```

2- for loop

```
    foreach($tmp_array->employees as $item)
    {
        echo $item[0] . "/" . $item[1] . "/" . $item[2];
    }
```

code brain tested. : )

Comment: You don't need `[i]`, since you're already looping through the elements.

Comment: It should be $tmp_array->employees, since json_decode() returns an object, not an array. This isn't Javascript, you can't treat them equivalently.

Comment: Thanks man :) With this I can display all the data. I want to display exactly a single employee's data like fisrt_name last_name and age. Say 5th row in the database

Answer (score 0):

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach ($decoded->employees as $emp)
  printf("%s %s\n", $emp[0], $emp[1]);
```

Comment: It's the first thing in the JSON data.

Comment: I am totally a beginner in JSON

Comment: JSON is irrelevant to this. After you decode it, you get a PHP object, and this object contains a property named "employees", and this property contains an array of employee data. You can see this when you  use `print_r($decoded)`, as you showed in your question.

Comment: See the line in your question beginning with `object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["employees"]=> array(21)`. That's the PHP object, and it says it has one property whose name is "employees" that contains an array with 21 elements.

Comment: Ok hope will soon enhance my knowledge in JSON and PHP